# ODATA VDM Approach results in SAP DBTech JDBC: Connection is currently in auto commit mode

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I had done my ODATA services using CAP. I had used S4SDK VDM approach in order to test my ODATA service in Integration Tests.

It was working well when I was using CAP 2.0. 
Now I had to upgrade to CAP 3.0.

After the upgrade, all VDM enabled Integration Tests fails due to below error,

***Caused by: com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: Connection is currently in auto commit mode.***

**My JUnit**

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() throws ODataException {
        mockUtil.mockDefaults();
        mockUtil.mockAuditLog();
    } 

@Before
    public void beforeEach() throws URISyntaxException, IOException, ODataException {
        mockUtil.mockDestination("localhorst", new URI("http://localhost:" + randomServerPort));
        erpConfCtx = new ErpConfigContext("localhorst");
        final String publicKey = FileUtils.readFile("publicKey.txt");
        final Map<String, String> verificationkey = ImmutableMap.of("verificationkey", publicKey);
        final JsonObject xsuaaServiceCredentials = new Gson().toJsonTree(verificationkey).getAsJsonObject();
        when(((ScpCfCloudPlatform) CloudPlatformAccessor.getCloudPlatform())
                .getXsuaaServiceCredentials(org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any(DecodedJWT.class)))
                        .thenReturn(xsuaaServiceCredentials);

        endpoint1Created = false;
        endpoint2Created = false;

        cloudServiceId1 = createLandscapeObject(CloudService.name(), "Cloud_Service_1_from_IT", "12345", "IT",
                "123456789", "PROD");
        assertNotNull(cloudServiceId1);

    } 

 private static UUID createLandscapeObject(String lsoType, String name, String customerNumber, String source,
        String tenantId, String tenantType) throws ODataException {

    LandscapeObjects landscapeObjects = new LandscapeObjects(null, null, null, null, null, name, "benufromit_test",
            lsoType, customerNumber, source, null, null, propertySet, null, null);

    LOG.info("Before creation of LandscapeObject");

    final LandscapeObjectsCreateFluentHelper lsoCreateHelper = lmsService.createLandscapeObjects(landscapeObjects)
            .withCustomHttpHeader("Authorization", jwToken).onRequestAndImplicitRequests();

    landscapeObjects = lsoCreateHelper.execute(erpConfCtx);

    return landscapeObjects.getId();

}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
2019-07-24 17:14:32.021 DEBUG 6292 --- [o-auto-1-exec-3] c.s.c.s.s.p.a.s.AuthorizationService     : Access control check on entity LandscapeService.LandscapeObjects for the operation WRITE.
2019-07-24 17:14:32.094 DEBUG 6292 --- [o-auto-1-exec-3] c.s.c.s.s.prov.api.request.Request       : Get first header value for name Accept-Language. Returning value for name Accept-Language.
2019-07-24 17:14:34.845 DEBUG 6292 --- [o-auto-1-exec-3] c.s.c.s.s.prov.rt.cds.HANADMLExecutor    : Insert SQL ::INSERT INTO LandscapeService_LandscapeObjects( createdAt ,createdBy ,modifiedAt ,name ,description ,modifiedBy ,id ,source ,customerNumber ,objType  ) VALUES ( ? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,?  )
2019-07-24 17:14:34.881 DEBUG 6292 --- [o-auto-1-exec-3] c.s.c.s.s.prov.rt.cds.HANADMLExecutor    : Insert SQL Rows Affected ::1
2019-07-24 17:14:34.881 DEBUG 6292 --- [o-auto-1-exec-3] c.s.c.s.s.prov.rt.cds.HANADMLExecutor    : Updating root delta entity if present
2019-07-24 17:14:34.887 DEBUG 6292 --- [o-auto-1-exec-3] c.s.c.s.s.prov.rt.cds.HANADMLExecutor    : Batch Insert SQL ::INSERT INTO LandscapeService_Properties( owner_id ,name ,value ,ptype ,source  ) VALUES ( ? ,? ,? ,? ,?  )
2019-07-24 17:14:34.903 DEBUG 6292 --- [o-auto-1-exec-3] c.s.c.s.s.prov.rt.cds.HANADMLExecutor    : Batch Insert SQL Rows Affected ::[I@3dd01bd0
2019-07-24 17:14:35.005 ERROR 6292 --- [o-auto-1-exec-3] c.s.s.p.v.r.c.CloudSDKODataErrorCallback : Request URL: http://localhost:55491/odata/v2/LandscapeService/LandscapeObjects
StatusCode:500

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at com.sap.cloud.servicesdk.spring.SpringConnectionProvider$1.invoke(SpringConnectionProvider.java:92) ~[spring.lib-1.32.2.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy198.commit(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.service.prov.rt.cds.wrapper.CDSTransactionManager.commitTransaction(CDSTransactionManager.java:27) ~[hana.connectivity.cds-core-1.32.2.jar:na]
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.service.prov.api.transaction.impl.TransactionHandler.commitTransaction(TransactionHandler.java:81) ~[api-1.32.2.jar:na]
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.service.prov.v2.rt.data.provider.HybridDataProvider.createEntity(HybridDataProvider.java:345) ~[odatav2-hybrid-1.32.2.jar:na]
    at com.sap.gateway.core.api.provider.data.GenericODataProcessor.createEntity(GenericODataProcessor.java:1113) ~[odata-core-1.32.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:79) ~[odatav2-lib-1.32.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.ODataRequestHandler.handle(ODataRequestHandler.java:131) ~[odatav2-lib-1.32.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.servlet.ODataServlet.handleRequest(ODataServlet.java:216) [odatav2-lib-1.32.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.servlet.ODataServlet.handle(ODataServlet.java:118) [odatav2-lib-1.32.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.servlet.ODataServlet.service(ODataServlet.java:85) [odatav2-lib-1.32.2.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestContextServletFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(RequestContextServletFilter.java:197) [servlet-2.17.0.jar:na]
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestContextCallable.call(RequestContextCallable.java:131) ~[servlet-2.17.0.jar:na]
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestContextServletFilter.doFilter(RequestContextServletFilter.java:209) [servlet-2.17.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:679) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
Caused by: com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: Connection is currently in auto commit mode.
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB._newInstance(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:191) ~[ngdbc-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0-57fcc0c5798796fe0e44414b13168345bf2eefed]
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB.newInstance(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:26) ~[ngdbc-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0-57fcc0c5798796fe0e44414b13168345bf2eefed]
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDB._commit(ConnectionSapDB.java:2390) ~[ngdbc-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0-57fcc0c5798796fe0e44414b13168345bf2eefed]
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDB.commit(ConnectionSapDB.java:356) ~[ngdbc-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0-57fcc0c5798796fe0e44414b13168345bf2eefed]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.commit(ProxyConnection.java:361) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.commit(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    ... 100 common frames omitte
```

Comment: At first glance: It does not look related to the OData VDM of the SAP Cloud SDK. Have you conducted troubleshooting wrt to JDBC connection?

Answer (score 1):

So you are using a JDBC driver somewhere, which supposedly behaves differently due to an update. From simple googling, I would say, you should add option `autocommit=off` to your JDBC resource address.

Syntax for reference:

```
jdbc:sap://<database_computer>[:<port>][/?<option1>[&<option2>]...]
```